# How does the Maslov index of a loop `project’ to the rotation number?

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology, contact-geometry, contact-topology

I’m trying to learn some Legendrian contact homology and the grading of the generators of the DGA are given by computing a fractional rotation number. In the symplectisation, this number is the Conley-Zehnder index (that also has something to do with the Maslov index). Basically, I would like to know how these two numbers are related, or maybe would like to know if there is a way of computing the Maslov index of a loop in the symplectisation that obviously `projects’ to the rotation number which we can compute just by combinatorial features of a Lagrangian projection.

Any help or references would be greatly appreciated!